# Estore wordpress theme not fully loading

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using demo version of Estore WordPress theme for my eCommerce site. and it is working fine yesterday. but when i open it today the homepage product slider height increases insanely long and other widgets are also not loading properly.

Url to site.

http://www.oriflamebeautyproducts.com/

Please help me to solve this issue because i can't understant that is it a theme issue or plugin issue..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with your theme. Your theme is the [Estore theme](https://demo.themegrill.com/estore/). 
When I compared the HTML content of the element `<div class="big-slider"></div>` I saw that alot of classes & inline styling was missing from the elements inside.

I guess the theme folder that is currently on your webserver is incomplete. With sliders its very common that javascript will add inline styling and classes to add the layout dynamically. I suggest you sync it with the original version. When the current website provided is the live domain I suggest you make a back-up first.

Comment: thanks for your help but now i got the problem, the problem is that i have choosed wrong product categories in widgets, because of that the page is not loading properly.